# Extracting rows based on ID and date. R-base

Tags: r

i have 2 data frames. one with a list of ID and dates of 700 persons, and another with 400.000 rows with date and several other variables for over 1000 persons.
example df1:

```
ID        date
1010      2014-05-31
1011      2015-08-27
1015      2011-04-15
...
```

example df2:

```
ID         Date           Operationcode
1010       2008-01-03     456
1010       2016-06-09     1234
1010       1999-10-04     123186
1010       2017-02-30     71181
1010       2005-05-05     201
1011       2008-04-02     46
1011       2009-09-09     1231
1515       2017-xx-xx     156
1015       2013-xx-xx     123
1615       1998-xx-xx     123
1015       2005-xx-xx     4156
1015       2007-xx-xx     123
1015       2016-xx-xx     213
```

now i wanna create a df3 where i only keep rows from df2 where the date is before df1 (when matched by ID).

so i get:

```
    ID         Date           Operationcode
    1010       2008-01-03     456
    1010       1999-10-04     123186
    1010       2005-05-05     201
    1015       2005-xx-xx     4156
    1015       2007-xx-xx     123
```

ive tried

```
df3 <- subset(df1, ID %in% df2$ID & df2$date < df1$date)
```

but keep giving me an error where something with the length of the last part, `df2$date < df1$date` doesnt match, and when I take a sampletest (look for the operationcode for 1 ID) i can see that i miss alot of rows before the date from df1. Any idea or solutions?

AND i only got base-R as its the hospitals computer which doesnt allow any downloading -.-

Comment: Why `|` in the condition? My understanding of your question is that you need a matching on ID between df1 and df2 *and* the condition on the date. What if you write `& df2$date < df1$date` instead?

Comment: @larsen , Sorry i used `&`. Made a typo when I wrote the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you could do something like this...

```
df3 <- merge(df2,df1,by="ID",all.x=TRUE) #merge in df1 date column
df3 <- df3[as.Date(df3$Date)<as.Date(df3$date),] #remove rows with invalid dates
#note that 'Date' is the df2 column, 'date' is the df1 version
df3 <- df3[!is.na(df3$ID),] #remove NA rows
df3$date <- NULL #remove df1 date column

df3
    ID       Date Operationcode
1 1010 2008-01-03           456
2 1010 1999-10-04        123186
3 1010 2005-05-05           201
6 1011 2009-09-09          1231
7 1011 2008-04-02            46
```

I'm not sure what is supposed to happen with the dates with `xx` in your data. Are they real? If they appear in the actual data, they will need special handling as otherwise they will not be converted to proper date format, so the calculation fails.